# JDBC setExplicitCachingEnabled(true) - performance/memory problems?

Tags: java, jdbc

Is there anything that I need to watch for after declaring `setExplicitCachingEnabled(true)` (or `setImplicitCachingEnabled(true)`), regarding memory/performance specifically for a JDBC connection?

Comment: That is not part of JDBC, so you may want to specify the driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable implicit statement caching on the OracleDataSource object, you need to perform the following steps:

1. Invoke OracleDataSource.getConnection() with the ImplicitCachingEnabled property set to true, or set ImplicitCachingEnabled on the OracleDataSource by calling OracleDataSource.setImplicitCachingEanble(true);
2. Set the cache size by invoking OracleDataSource.setMaxStatements(int maxNumberOfStatements)
   eg: OracleDataSource.setMaxStatements(10);